# Android Hover View Boundaries to listen on exit and enter view bounds

Tags: android, popup, android-view, ontouchlistener, android-viewgroup

I am trying to implement something like a custom keyboard that builds fully dynamic
My problem is that I want to when hovering any view just show a hint [bigger view for the same one]
and I want if I am still hovering I want my hint to still appear to the user.

Example: Samsung Keyboard if you focused on a key from the keyboard it will show a popup and if you moved around it will show a popup for each letter you will enter and hide the popup of the letter you left.

I found this workaround solution that depends on long-press but it uses handler and I still can not detect I exit the view boundaries or entered it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38910646/2172590

I want to make a full dynamic keyboard that has a scroll inside it like a recycler view and I want to detect the enter and exit for each item in the recycler view and recycler view has a grid layout manager

[image]